# Sample code to send an IPv6 packet in C

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6, ddos

My C skills are VERY rusty, and I need some help:

Does anyone know how to open a socket and send an IPv6 packet in C?
The goal is to test a mechanism preventing a Denial Of Service attack over IPv6.
I would very much appreciate if anyone had some sample code that i could work with, or any reference that could help me understand what I have to do.

Thank you.

Comment: Generally speaking it's just the same as sending data over IPv4, it's basically just another `sockaddr` structure used (`sockaddr_in6` instead of `sockaddr_in`) and a different address family (`AF_INET6` instead of `AF_INET`).

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much the same as for IPv4. The only differences are: using the IPv6 domain when creating a socket:

```
s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

And binding/connecting with `struct sockaddr_in6` for the address.